# Compare the old get_theme_mod($name) to the new get_theme_mod($name) return value

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, customization, themes

I want to have this kind of validation in my code:

```
if (/*OLD*/get_theme_mod($name) != /*NEW*/get_theme_mod($name)) {
    // do something..
}
```

That code will execute after pressing the *"Save & Publish"* button in the `Appearance -> Customize` of a theme. Is there a right way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you really using the same `$name` variable twice? If so, this statement is useless as it will always evaluate to false

Comment: @shea No, what I mean is, every time an admin press the _"Save & Publish"_ button in the Customize area, it will compare the previous and the new `get_theme_mod($name)`. If they're not equal, some script will be executed, so if its setting have changed they'll become not equal because the new one is not `false` anymore.. Anyway, I already found a solution for this, I'll try to post it if I have time...

Comment: @shea Please check [my answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/192073/73330) to get what I mean. If you think you have a better solution, if you're willing don't forget to show it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions that I've found, is to store the set `get_theme_mod($name)` into a PHP `$_SESSION["$name"]`. If the session exist, compare the new `get_theme_mod($name)` to that old `$_SESSION["$name"]`, if they're not the same then `// do something..`:

```
// Check if the user is an admin for validation to improve performance.
if (current_user_can( 'manage_options' )) {
    session_start();

    // If the session is not set, the OLD is not equal to the NEW.
    if (!isset($_SESSION['theme_mod_name']) {
        // do something..

        $_SESSION['theme_mod_name'] = get_theme_mod('theme_mod_name');
    } else {
        $theme_mod_name   = get_theme_mod('theme_mod_name');
        $theme_mod_name_s = $_SESSION['theme_mod_name'];

        // Check if the OLD is equal to the NEW.
        if ($theme_mod_name !== $theme_mod_name_s) {
            // do something..

            // Override the existing session for future validation.
            $_SESSION['theme_mod_name'] = get_theme_mod('theme_mod_name');
        }
    }
}
```

But it have a little con, an admin needs to visit its own site or perform a `refresh` setting transport to perform the validation.